# Which processes do contribute to "commit charge"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

I want to put the question squarely: what is the contribution of every process into [commited memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_charge). Process Explorer refers to the total memory committed and `commit charge` but only `Private bytes`, `Working Set` and `Virtual Memory` is reported for the processes. I see no process that has the commit column. Yet, I want to know who committed all my memory.

Comment: Private bytes gives the committed private virtual memory for each process. The other types of memory allocation that contribute to commit charge cannot be related to a particular process.

Comment: Why don't you want this to be the answer? What are the non-process contributions to the commit charge?

Comment: I didn't think it was a complete answer to what you were asking. Amongst other allocations that contribute to the commit charge are page tables, kernel stacks, paged and non-paged pool and various types of mapped memory. If you are happy with this I will make it an answer.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty decent. I look for the process to kill that eats all my memory. If you tell that the private bytes exhaust all process contributions then I wonder what else may be needed for completeness?

Comment: There may be some confusion here. Committed memory is virtual memory and represents memory that the system has guaranteed will be available if needed. It can be either RAM or page file. In fact, it will not occupy either RAM or page file until it has been referenced. When the commit limit is reached Windows will attempt to expand the page file. If you are concerned about physical RAM usage, you need to look at Working Set which is the ammount of physical memory used by a process. You should be aware that Windows tries to use as much physical memory as possible.